# How to create a video from sequence images Android Java programmatically

Tags: java, android

I want to create a video from sequence of images, the images are of same size and I don't want to add any audio file to it so that's going to not hard.

What I need to do for that please explain, what line of code should I need to use for this, or if you have the sample code for it?

Comment: Try with a TextureView.

Comment: Hope this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/15052530/10458040

Comment: Hi bro, Actually I want the mp4 video file as output,I don't want to show animation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use ffmpeg. https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper

This is a  wapper library for java.

Comment: While the advice is on point, and FFMPEG (complex?) filters might be a decent start, I dont think that someone asking for code to do that will make sense of the ffmpeg java wrapper at all...

Comment: As i understand. The OP have mutiple images and he want to create video from them by using java. The library is simple for beginners with meaningful command. I dont think OP want to show it on the screen only.

Comment: Yes, I wat to take .mp4 file as result.

Comment: But it not cleared to use ffmpeg , please you can explain me more, Please. 

Comment: When you access the github page, they will guide you how to get the library.
`FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder()
.addInput("/Users/christie/java/ffmpeg/image%03d.png")
    .addOutput("output.mp4")
    .setVideoFrameRate(FFmpeg.FPS_24)
    .done();`
According to need.

Comment: Thanks bro, I I'll try, if I got any problem then I'll ask to you. Thanks for help, Remember my name Aryan, Thank you so much bro.

Comment: @user:3562932 please See This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62326034/how-to-make-video-from-images-ffmpeg-java